# Kea DHCP Upload leases6 with key-admin-tool on maria db

Tags: json, mariadb, dhcp

I set up two DHCP v6 KEA servers with MariaDB as backend for dhcp leases and works fine. I set a cronjob to perform a lease-dump every hour using the kea-admin tool in case of MySQL failure. The problem is t when I do lease-upload the csv with the kea-admin tool, the leases are uploaded to the database, but the DHCP service generates the following errors and no device can UPDATE the lease.
Both MySQL and the DHCP have the same time zone. Maridb version is (mariadb 10.6.12-MariaDB)
and the Kea DHCP version is 2.4.1

ERROR [kea-dhcp6.alloc-engine/] ALLOC_ENGINE_V6_EXTEND_ERROR duid=[.........], tid=...: allocation engine experienced error with attempting to extend lease lifetime: unable to execute for , reason: Unexpected end of JSON text in argument 1 to function 'json_extract' (error code 4037)

If someone knows how to solve this i will be very grateful !!!!!!!

Thank you !

I did a manual import of the data, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Seems like the table, `kea-dhcp6.alloc-engine` has an insufficiently sized column for storing JSON data an truncate it on insertion. Look at `show create table {tablename}` and see if the column can [increaed in size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/blob-and-text-data-types/) using [ALTER TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/). Add full query and datastructures by editing your question.